# Is the closure of the interior of a closed set closed?

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is closed. Is the closure of the interior of $A$ equal to $A$? $A = \overline{\text{int}(A)}$?

Comment: the closure of any set is closed

Comment: you can use `\mathring A` for the interior $\mathring A$.

Comment: Your title question (answered by the comment of @janmarqz) is different from question that follows.

Comment: @zwim: I prefer the notation $A^\circ$ for the interior. Mostly because it also works well with more complex expressions, like $(A\cup B\cup C)^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Not in general. Any singleton in the real numbers is a counter example.

$\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed and its interior is empty. But since the empty set is closed, it is also its closure.

Hence $\{0\} \neq \emptyset = \overline{\emptyset} = \overline{\text{int}(\{0\})}$

Sets for which this is true are called [regular closed](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Regular_Closed_Set).

Answer (score 0):

It's closed, but when $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A° =\emptyset$, for instance, it's not equal to $A$.